# Sum values based on comparison of two different DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to check if a value in one df is between two values of another df. If so the values of the first df shall be summed.

```
df1['MyNewCol'] = df2[(df2['date'] >= df1['Startdate']) and (df2['date'] <= df1['enddate'])].sum('values', axis = 1)
```

This is what my code looks like and it shall check if the date mentioned in df2 is between startdate and enddate. If so it shall print the sum of values.

I get "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" as error. Is there an easy way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: `and` tests whether both expressions are logically True while `&` (when used with True/False values) tests if both are True

Answer (score 0):

Size of series of two dataframes are not the same for comparison or the indexes aren't similar. So, the operator `>=` can't compare in these cases.

`and` is a python operator. You need logical `&` for your case

```
(df2['date'] >= df1['Startdate']) & (df2['date'] <= df1['enddate'])
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the indexes similar without deleting data out of one of the dataframes?